# Plot Spectrogram and FFT plots from samples collected by Atheros AR9271

Tags: fft, python, spectrogram

I'm entering the world of signal processing, and as one of my first projects I've decided to plot a [spectrogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html) and [FFT Plot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html).

The samples comes from an [Atheros AR9271](https://aliexpress.com/item/4001100317465.html). More details can be found here: [The AR9280 and later NICs have the ability to report FFT data from the baseband](https://wiki.freebsd.org/dev/ath_hal(4)/SpectralScan)

Currently, I have a small script, [similar to this](https://gist.github.com/bastibl/50d1449a30eba9e5d55e).
What I wanted to do, is to use the **raw** abs(|I|+|Q|) which is given for each of the 56 bins and build my data from there.

According to [1](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html) I can do the following:

1. `bin_sum = 10*log(sum[i=1..56](b(i)^2)`
2. `power(i) = noise_floor + RSSI + 10*log(b(i)^2) - bin_sum`

So I have power[dBm] for each of the 56 bins.

From here I simply append the power series for the 56 bins to the overall samples series.

```
samples = np.append(samples, power)
```

**This might be mistake #1**, appending the samples as such.

I have tried to calculate fft(using [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html)):

```
center_frequency = 2432 * (1e6)  # Channel 5 center frequency
half_bandwidth = 20 * (1e6) / 2
fs = 2 * 2.4 * (1e9) # **Maybe mistake #2**
N = samples.size
T = 1.0 / fs
yf = fft(samples)
xf = np.linspace(center_frequency-half_bandwidth, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), N // 2)
plot(xf, 2.0 / N * np.abs(yf[:N // 2]))
```

And regarding the spectrogram(using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html))

```
specgram(samples, Fs=1.0 / fs, cmap='plasma')
```

**Problems:**

1. I'm almost sure I'm making at least few mistakes and I don't know where.
2. The x-axis for the spectrogram does not match the frequencies I'm sampling(should it?). In the case of the FFT Plot I made the adjustments to `xf`.

**Question:**
What mistakes and bad assumptions am I doing?

Regarding what I've wrote, which I'm not sure is correct, here are my understandings

1. fs - Why I've used: `2 * 2.4 * (1e9)`? Due to 802.11n on AR9271 and I'm working on the 20 mode, which is 2.4GHz with bandwidth of 20Mhz, I was thinking that `nyquist theorem` is applicable here, is it?.
2. `xf` adjustment I've made so that it will plot around the center frequency. I'm not sure if its the right way to do so.
3. And most importantly, is the samples array I construct as I did, which is simply appending the power array so that I have: `samples = [bin0Power_fftFrame0, bin1Power_fftFrame0, ..., bin55Power_fftFrame0, ...... , bin0Power_fftFrameN, bin1Power_fftFrame0, ..., bin55Power_fftFrameN]`

Any help over one of my misunderstandings/mistakes would be really helpful.

Comment: `N = samples.size` should usually be `len(samples)` since samples could be N-dimensional with multiple channels.  What is `samples.shape`? `Fs=1.0 / fs` Shouldn't that be `Fs=fs`? :)